# How to create a multiple of login with Tables Different?

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to create a login system with using two different tables one for the board administrator othe apar customer and am having a problem because both logins use by default the Users table and I'm unable to change ..

Thank you for any solution.

Comment: Will you have two different login forms for these two, or they all log in through the same form?